# How to fill a form by id of input in Casperjs?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I am using Casperjs 1.1.0-beta3 and trying to fill a form by an 'id' selector.  I have successfully have used "input[name='userID']" but using an 'id' as a selector always fails with an error similar to the below.

CasperError: Errors encountered while filling form: no field matching css selector "#header-my-account-userid" in form; no field matching css selector "#header-my-account-password" in form

Method 1 works fine.  Method 2, 3, 4 all fail.  I ONLY TRY ONE METHOD AT A TIME AND COMMENT THE OTHERS OUT.  I also cut the extra form tags out for this question.

I found this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568186/casperjs-seems-unable-to-recognise-password-field-on-login-form) on the same subject it still doesn't work.

Any ideas?

HTML

```
                <input id="header-my-account-userid" name="userID" class="m-my-account-userid" maxlength="80" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Email or Rewards #" type="text">
                <input id="header-my-account-password" name="password" class="m-my-account-password" maxlength="20" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Password" type="password">
                <button type="submit" name="submit" id="header-my-account-sign-in" class="analytics-click m-button-default"  title="Sign In">Sign In</button>
```

Casperjs Script

```
    casper.then(function() {
        casper.waitForSelector('form[name=directLoginForm]', function() {
    // Method 1 Works
            this.fillSelectors("form[name=directLoginForm]", {
                'input[name=userID]' : username,
                'input[name=password]' : password
            }, true);

    // Method 2 Does not work
            this.fillSelectors("form[name=directLoginForm]", {
                'input[id="header-my-account-userid"]' : username,
                'input[id="header-my-account-password"]' : password
            }, true);

    // Method 3 Does not work
            this.fillSelectors("form[name=directLoginForm]", {
                'header-my-account-userid' : username,
                'header-my-account-password' : password
            }, true);

    // Method 4 Does not work
            this.fillSelectors("form[name=directLoginForm]", {
                '#header-my-account-userid' : username,
                '#header-my-account-password' : password
            }, true);

        });
    });
```

Comment: Well, that's strange, it should work, try this.sendKeys('input[id="header-my-account-userid"]', username);

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I would think it would work also. I have seen several examples of method #2 supposedly working for people. The only far fetched idea I had was that in my case the 'name' and 'id' are different. Plus '-'s in the id itself. I can't believe that would be the problem but I have seen bizzare stuff before. I will try your idea and get back to later as it's only 4:30am local :)

Comment: @Fanch,  I tried your code snippet.  Pycharm reads it as invalid and the script hangs when I use it.  Thanks for trying tho. :)

Comment: One a side note, I learned that you can run casperjs scripts thru phantomjs with a tiny modification.  I was able to use my Method #1 an it worked perfectly.  However,  using method #2 and running thru phantomjs crashed it.  Bug?????

Answer (score 0):

Well i tried, they all work (except 3 because your selector is invalid).
I put the bool to false to see the changes, but you shouldn't have 'Errors encountered while filling form: no field matching css selector "#header-my-account-userid'.

It's not a casper error so, it's specific to your case. It doesn't recognize your id for obscure reasons.

```
this.sendKeys('input[id="header-my-account-userid"]', username);
```

sendKeys works also.

Answer (score 0):

A minimal example revealed that only method 3 shouldn't work. I suspect you check for 'working' form by checking if the next page loads. It might be the case that casper doesn't find the submit button. Try explicitly clicking the button.

Additionally, PhantomJS has sometimes a problem with non-quoted attribute selectors. You should change

```
"form[name=directLoginForm]"
```

to

```
"form[name='directLoginForm']"
```

Comment: It's finding the button fine. The error is about finding the 'inputs' using certain selectors.  See the error in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Wait for the form to be loaded to fill the form using the selectors.Use have waitForSelector(),waitFor(),wait() etc other than waitForResource()

```
casper.start('your_url_here',function(){
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
});    

casper.waitForResource("your_url_here",function() {
    this.fillSelectors('#loginform', {
        'input[name="Email"]' : 'your_email',
        'input[name="Passwd"]': 'your_password'
    }, true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I find that this happens when casperJS is too fast for the browser and a `casper.wait()` will solve the issue.

This is an example:

```
// Make a test order
    casper.then(function() {
        casper.waitForSelector('#onestepcheckout-form', function() {
            this.fillSelectors('#onestepcheckout-form', {
                'input[id="billing:telephone"]': '12344534',
                'input[id="billing:postcode"]': '432323',
                'input[id="billing:city"]': 'London',
                'input[id="billing:street1"]': 'Lambada is a good music'
            }, false);
        })

        casper.wait(5000, function() {
            this.fillSelectors('#onestepcheckout-form', {
                '#sagepaydirectpro_cc_owner': 'Fizipit o Moyazoci',
                'input[id="agreement-1"]': true
            }, true);
        })
        this.test.pass('form populated');
    });
```

Comment: True, but I think it's always better to use 'casper.waitForSelector' before I do anything.  That way if the website takes even longer than 5000 you should be covered.

Comment: @fatfantasma indeed and you don't wait longer if it appears faster than 5s